# Using style modifiers & pattern parameters inside of a rendered pseudo pattern

Tags: mustache, patternlab.io

I am using the [Node version of pattern lab](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node) and have a pattern mustache file that contains the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="{{ styleModifier }}">{{ linkCopy }}</a>
```

I call this pattern partial in a mustache file like the code below:

```
{{> name-of-pattern-partial:css-class(linkCopy: 'Link Text') }}
```

The pattern partial renders the following code in the .mustache pattern:

```
<a href="#" class="css-class">Link Text</a>
```

In the pseudo pattern however the code is being rendered as follows:

```
<a href="#" class=""></a>
```

Is there a limitation in Pattern Lab, Mustache or Pattern Lab Node that does not allow the use of pattern parameters and style modifiers in rendered pseudo patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was identified as a bug in the node project, here: https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/issues/250

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. I will keep an eye on the status of this issue on the github page.  Thanks a bunch @allicarn !

Comment: It appears that the patternlab community here on stack overflow is not super active, however their github is thriving!  I'm finding out for myself that it may be better to toss questions and issues in that direction.